# async chaining blocks webapi call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I've a flow: ***WebApi > ServiceFramework > DBLayer > MongoDB***.

Since its a new application, I ensured to have async from the ground up in all layers. However, when my DB Layer has async code, webapi never gets a response back.

**API CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetAllRecords()
{
   var result = FrameworkApi.GetRecords().Result;
   return Ok(result);
}
```

**above calls  > FRAMEWORK API**

```
public async Task<List<Record>> GetRecords()
{
    return await FrameworkDbApi.GetRecords();
}
```

**above calls > DB FRAMEWORK API (which Calls MongoDB)**

```
public async Task<List<Record>> GetRecords()
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>                
       NoSqlDocumentClient.GetDefaultDatabase().Result.
       GetCollection<Record>("record").AsQueryable().ToList());            

      //following Synchronous version works..but defeats the purpose  
      //return NoSqlDocumentClient.GetDefaultDatabase().Result
      //       .GetCollection<Record>("record").AsQueryable().ToList();
}
```

However, when the operations in either DBLayer or Framework are invoked via test case, I do get result. But when invoked via WebApi controller, the asynchronous version never returns a response while synchronous version works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when invoked via WebApi controller, the asynchronous version never
>   returns a response while synchronous version works fine.

That's because your actual request is deadlocking. When you invoke the method via WebAPI, which has a [SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx), you're seeing the deadlock, in contrary to your test which hasn't got one, when the test runs fine. This is the reason why you [shouldn't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Your call-chain should look like this in order to avoid deadlocking (this is what it means to go "async all the way":

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllRecordsAsync()
{
   var result = await FrameworkApi.GetRecordsAsync();
   return Ok(result);
}

public Task<List<Record>> GetRecordsAsync()
{
    return FrameworkDbApi.GetRecordsAsync();
}

public async Task<List<Record>> GetRecordsAsync()
{
    var result = await NoSqlDocumentClient.GetDefaultDatabase();
    return result.GetCollection<Record>("record").AsQueryable().ToList();          
}
```